# joomla/k2 php template overrides

Tags: php, templates, layout, joomla, joomla-k2

Really need some help after many hours of banging head against a brick wall!

Basically I have a Joomla News page made in the K2 component. The page would have the top story, the next two, then the next four and the next four after that all with their own class so they can be styled differently for emphasis (like most news websites).

So there would be one row of one column - main news (with items image and text cut off after about 150 words with a 'read more')
second row - two columns - next two news pieces (with items image and text cut off after about 150 words with a 'read more')
third row - four columns - next four news pieces (with items image and text cut off after about 150 words with a 'read more')
fourth row - one column of eight links (no image just the title linked)

This is the file I'm trying to amend:

```
    <?php


// no direct access

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$selectedFilters=$params->get('extraFieldsSelect'); //get selected fields in module params



?>

<div id="k2ModuleBox<?php echo $module->id; ?> k2FiltrifyContainer" class="k2Filtrify k2ItemsBlock<?php if($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')) echo ' '.$params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">

    <?php if($params->get('itemPreText')): ?>

    <p class="modulePretext"><?php echo $params->get('itemPreText'); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>



    <!--Filtrify Placeholder-->

    <div id="k2FiltrifyPlaceHolder"></div>



    <?php //set placeholder, if LEGEND is the selected callback method

    if($placeholder == 'legend'): ?>

        <!--Filtrify legend placeholder-->

        <div id="legend"><i><?php echo JText::_('K2_VIEWING_ALL'); ?></i></div>

    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php  //set placeholder, if PAGINATION is the selected callback method

    if($placeholder == 'pagination'): ?>

        <!--Filtrify pagination placeholder-->

        <div id="pagination"></div>

    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php if(count($items)): //Filtrify Container?>

      <ul id="k2FiltrifyContainer">

        <p>
          <?php foreach ($items as $keyItem=>$item):    ?>



            <?php

                // Define a CSS class for the last container on each row

                if( (($keyItem+1)%($params->get('num_columns'))==0) || count($items)<$params->get('num_columns') )

                    $lastContainer= ' itemContainerLast';

                else

                    $lastContainer='';

                ?>

          <li class="itemContainer<?php echo $lastContainer; ?>" <?php echo (count($items)==1) ? '' : ' style="width:'.number_format(100/$params->get('num_columns'), 1).'%;"'; ?>





          <?php 



          if( count($item->extra_fields) && $selectedFilters != ''): //check if there are extrafields and selected fields?>

                <?php foreach ($item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): //adding extrafields as data parameter?>

                    <?php if(in_array($extraField->id,(array)$selectedFilters, TRUE)) : ?>

                             data-<?php echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-zA-yA-y0-9а-яА-Яa-zA-Z?-??-?sctzlldSCTZLD]/ui", "_", $extraField->name); ?>="<?php echo $extraField->value; //set the values, and remove special chars?>"

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>





          <?php if($params->get('showCatFilter')==1): //check for param - show category filter?>

                data-<?php echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-zA-yA-y0-9а-яА-Яá-źÁ-ŹΑ-Ωα-ωščťžľĺďŠČŤŽĹĎ]/ui", "_", JText::_('K2_CATEGORIES')); ?>="<?php echo $item->categoryname;?>"





            <?php endif; ?>



            <?php if($params->get('showTagFilter')==1): //check for param - show tag filter?>

                data-<?php echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-zA-yA-y0-9а-яА-Яá-źÁ-ŹΑ-Ωα-ωščťžľĺďŠČŤŽĹĎ]/ui", "_", JText::_('K2_TAGS')); ?>="<?php foreach ($item->tags as $tag): ?><?php echo $tag->name; ?>, <?php endforeach; ?>"

            <?php endif; ?>



        >
        </p>
        <p>
          <?php if(isset($item->event->BeforeDisplay)): ?>

          <!-- Plugins: BeforeDisplay -->

          <?php echo $item->event->BeforeDisplay; ?>

          <?php endif; ?>





          <!-- K2 Plugins: K2BeforeDisplay -->

          <?php echo $item->event->K2BeforeDisplay; ?>



          <?php if($params->get('itemAuthorAvatar')): ?>

          <a class="k2Avatar moduleItemAuthorAvatar" rel="author" href="<?php echo $item->authorLink; ?>">

            <img src="<?php echo $item->authorAvatar; ?>" alt="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->author); ?>" style="width:<?php echo $avatarWidth; ?>px;height:auto;" />

          </a>

          <?php endif; ?>



          <?php if($params->get('itemTitle')): ?>

          <a class="moduleItemTitle" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>

          <?php endif; ?>



          <?php if($params->get('itemAuthor')): ?>

        </p>
          <div class="moduleItemAuthor">

              <?php echo K2HelperUtilities::writtenBy($item->authorGender); ?>



                    <?php if(isset($item->authorLink)): ?>

                    <a rel="author" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->author); ?>" href="<?php echo $item->authorLink; ?>"><?php echo $item->author; ?></a>

                    <?php else: ?>

                    <?php echo $item->author; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>



                    <?php if($params->get('userDescription')): ?>

                    <?php echo $item->authorDescription; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>



                </div>

                <?php endif; ?>





            <?php if(isset($item->event->AfterDisplayTitle)): ?>

                 <!-- Plugins: AfterDisplayTitle -->

                 <?php echo $item->event->AfterDisplayTitle; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>



          <!-- K2 Plugins: K2AfterDisplayTitle -->

          <?php echo $item->event->K2AfterDisplayTitle; ?>





            <?php if(isset($item->event->BeforeDisplayContent)): ?>

              <!-- Plugins: BeforeDisplayContent -->

                <?php echo $item->event->BeforeDisplayContent; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>



          <!-- K2 Plugins: K2BeforeDisplayContent -->

          <?php echo $item->event->K2BeforeDisplayContent; ?>



          <?php if($params->get('itemImage') || $params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>

          <div class="moduleItemIntrotext">

              <?php if($params->get('itemImage') && isset($item->image)): ?>

              <a class="moduleItemImage" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_CONTINUE_READING'); ?> &quot;<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>&quot;">

                <img src="<?php echo $item->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>"/>

              </a>

              <?php endif; ?>



            <?php if($params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>

            <?php echo $item->introtext; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

          </div>

          <?php endif; ?>

          <div class="clr"></div>



          <?php if($params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($item->extra_fields)): ?>

          <div class="moduleItemExtraFields">

              <b><?php echo JText::_('K2_ADDITIONAL_INFO'); ?></b>

              <ul>

                <?php foreach ($item->extra_fields as $extraField): ?>

                        <?php if($extraField->value): ?>

                        <li class="type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">

                            <span class="moduleItemExtraFieldsLabel"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?></span>

                            <span class="moduleItemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>

                            <div class="clr"></div>

                        </li>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

              </ul>

          </div>

          <?php endif; ?>



          <div class="clr"></div>



          <?php if($params->get('itemVideo')): ?>

          <div class="moduleItemVideo">

            <?php echo $item->video ; ?>

            <span class="moduleItemVideoCaption"><?php echo $item->video_caption ; ?></span>

            <span class="moduleItemVideoCredits"><?php echo $item->video_credits ; ?></span>

          </div>

          <?php endif; ?>



          <div class="clr"></div>





            <?php if(isset($item->event->AfterDisplayContent)): ?>

                  <!-- Plugins: AfterDisplayContent -->

                  <?php echo $item->event->AfterDisplayContent; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>



          <!-- K2 Plugins: K2AfterDisplayContent -->

          <?php echo $item->event->K2AfterDisplayContent; ?>



          <?php if($params->get('itemDateCreated')): ?>

          <span class="moduleItemDateCreated"><?php echo JText::_('K2_WRITTEN_ON') ; ?> <?php echo JHTML::_('date', $item->created, JText::_('K2_DATE_FORMAT_LC2')); ?></span>

          <?php endif; ?>



          <?php if($params->get('itemCategory')): ?>

          <?php echo JText::_('K2_IN') ; ?> <a class="moduleItemCategory" href="<?php echo $item->categoryLink; ?>"><?php echo $item->categoryname; ?></a>

          <?php endif; ?>



          <?php if($params->get('itemTags') && count($item->tags)>0): ?>

          <div class="moduleItemTags">

            <b><?php echo JText::_('K2_TAGS'); ?>:</b>

            <?php foreach ($item->tags as $tag): ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $tag->link; ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

          </div>

          <?php endif; ?>



          <?php if($params->get('itemAttachments') && count($item->attachments)): ?>

                <div class="moduleAttachments">

                    <?php foreach ($item->attachments as $attachment): ?>

                    <a title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($attachment->titleAttribute); ?>" href="<?php echo $attachment->link; ?>"><?php echo $attachment->title; ?></a>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                </div>

          <?php endif; ?>



                <?php if($params->get('itemCommentsCounter') && $componentParams->get('comments')): ?>      

                    <?php if(!empty($item->event->K2CommentsCounter)): ?>

                        <!-- K2 Plugins: K2CommentsCounter -->

                        <?php echo $item->event->K2CommentsCounter; ?>

                    <?php else: ?>

                        <?php if($item->numOfComments>0): ?>

                        <a class="moduleItemComments" href="<?php echo $item->link.'#itemCommentsAnchor'; ?>">

                            <?php echo $item->numOfComments; ?> <?php if($item->numOfComments>1) echo JText::_('K2_COMMENTS'); else echo JText::_('K2_COMMENT'); ?>

                        </a>

                        <?php else: ?>

                        <a class="moduleItemComments" href="<?php echo $item->link.'#itemCommentsAnchor'; ?>">

                            <?php echo JText::_('K2_BE_THE_FIRST_TO_COMMENT'); ?>

                        </a>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>



                <?php if($params->get('itemHits')): ?>

                <span class="moduleItemHits">

                    <?php echo JText::_('K2_READ'); ?> <?php echo $item->hits; ?> <?php echo JText::_('K2_TIMES'); ?>

                </span>

                <?php endif; ?>



                <?php if($params->get('itemReadMore') && $item->fulltext): ?>

                <a class="moduleItemReadMore" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">

                    <?php echo JText::_('K2_READ_MORE'); ?>

                </a>

                <?php endif; ?>



            <?php if(isset($item->event->AfterDisplay)): ?>

                 <!-- Plugins: AfterDisplayContent -->

                 <?php echo $item->event->AfterDisplay; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>



          <!-- K2 Plugins: K2AfterDisplay -->

          <?php echo $item->event->K2AfterDisplay; ?>

          <div class="clr"></div>

        </li>



        <?php if((($keyItem+1)%($params->get('num_columns'))==0) && (($placeholder != 'pagination'))) : ?>

        <div class="clr"></div>

        <?php endif; ?>





        <?php endforeach; ?>



        <li class="clearList"></li>

      </ul>

  <?php endif; ?>



    <?php if($params->get('itemCustomLink')): ?>

    <a class="moduleCustomLink" href="<?php echo $params->get('itemCustomLinkURL'); ?>" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($itemCustomLinkTitle); ?>"><?php echo $itemCustomLinkTitle; ?></a>

    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php if($params->get('feed')): ?>

    <div class="k2FeedIcon">

        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&format=feed&moduleID='.$module->id); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_THIS_RSS_FEED'); ?>">

            <span><?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_THIS_RSS_FEED'); ?></span>

        </a>

        <div class="clr"></div>

    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>



</div>
```

Like I say, I've tried and tried to make this template work, but have got nowhere!

Comment: which file are you overriding?

Comment: Its the default.php file that is displayed above. On page it produces a straight <li> but would a layout like suggested.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You try it with wrong file! This file belongs to Filtrify Module!

You must:

1. set as template for category "default"
2. edit K2 native category settings,
3. edit K2 native category item settings,
4. edit K2 native
   item settings,

After you set all native K2 parameters, you must clone your default k2 template. Do it so:

- go into components/com_k2/templates.
- Copy all, what you see, locally.
- Then create in you templates/your-template/html folder named com_k2.
- Copy into it all, what you got befor from components/com_k2/templates.
- Then duplicate folder named "default" and give them own name. This will be your K2 template for overrides.

Then go into K2 administration and change template of you category, which you set up befor, from default to the new name. Just now you can begin with template overrides, but ONLY inside of templates/your template/html/com_k2/your-k2-template. The files you need to override are category-item.php for category view and item.php for single item view.

Comment: It is not enough to copy the `default` folder located in the `templates` directory - you need all files (or at least most of them).